# Printing some hidden and some unhidden sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up a button to print some sheets in a workbook but I would like to hide some of the sheets but still print them. How do I change the following code so that it prints a mixture of hidden and unhidden sheets.

```
Private Sub PrintNew_Click()
If Sheets("New").Range("email").Value <> "email" And ActiveSheet.Name = "New" Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Email Address Needs to be Completed", vbInformation
If response = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = True
response = MsgBox("Do you really want to print?", vbOKCancel)
If response = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("copy") = "Customer Copy"
Sheets("New").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("Disclosure").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("GAP").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("TCF").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("Legal").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Range("copy") = "File Copy"
Sheets("New").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("Disclosure").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("GAP").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("TCF").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Sheets("Legal").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
Range("copy") = "Customer Copy"
End If
End Sub
```

I would like to be able to hide "Disclosure", "GAP", "TCF" & "Legal"

Thanks in advance for any help
John Davies

Comment: Turn off screen update, print, hide, turn on screen update

Comment: Sorry that does not make any sense to me.  I would like the sheets mentioned to remain hidden at all times but the other sheets mentioned should remain visible in the workbook it that helps.

Comment: When you turn off the screen update, the sheet visibility would not be visible on the screen. So once you have done whatever you need to do, turn on the screen update again. No one will know what happened in the background.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but it is not screen updating that I require.  The sheets mentioned are already hidden as I don't want their tabs showing.  The other sheets are visible at all times.  What I require is that the hidden sheets and the visible sheets are printing when I click on the button.  If I hide the sheets mentioned and click on the print button i get a run time error because the '1004'.  Is there a way to amend the code so that the hidden sheets will print?

Comment: When you switch off screen update, even if you unhide the sheets, it wont be visible. So unhide those sheets, print them, and then hide them again.

Comment: Is there a way to print the hidden sheets sheets without unhiding them?

Comment: Not that I know off. Will like others to pitch in if there is any other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Users looking for a method to print a list of worksheets regardless of their visibility setting try this:

Note: Print two copies (1st as `Customer Copy` and 2nd as `File Copy`)

```
Sub Wsh_Print()
Dim aWsh As Variant
Rem Array with name of all worksheets to be printed
aWsh = [{"New","Disclosure","GAP","TCF","Legal"}]
Dim Wsh As Worksheet, vWsh As Variant
Dim vxWshVisible As Variant, b As Byte
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For b = 1 To 2
        For Each vWsh In aWsh
            Set Wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vWsh)
            With Wsh
                .Range("copy") = Choose(b, "Customer Copy", "File Copy")
                vxWshVisible = .Visible                 'Record original worksheet visibility
                .Visible = xlSheetVisible               'Make worksheet visible
                .PrintOut IgnorePrintAreas:=False       'Print worksheet
                .Visible = vxWshVisible                 'Reset original worksheet visibility
                .Range("copy") = "Customer Copy"
    End With: Next: Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```